# How do I SELECT and COUNT from two diferent tables to get the "like count" of a post in one query?

Tags: php, mysql, select

I'm kind of noobie to this, but I'm trying to learn, I have two tables, the first one (NEWS) has all the information about posts of a blog, it has the follow structure:

```
* NEWS (TABLE 1)
- id_new
- id_category
- date
- ...etc
- **likes**
```

and I have a second table:

```
* LIKES (TABLE 2)
- id_like
- id_new
- id_user
- date
- ip_user
```

So, I want to select all the rows from TABLE 1 to display all the news but also i want to count the likes and get the COUNT of each new as **like** column.

Comment: use a left join and group by id_news. aggregate id_like using Count(id_like)

Comment: Simplest solution SELECT A.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM B WHERE B.a_id = A.id) AS TOT FROM A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach left joins the `NEWS` table to a subquery which finds the number of likes for each news story.

```
SELECT
    t1.*,
    COALESCE(t2.likes, 0) AS likes
FROM NEWS t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT id_new, COUNT(*) AS likes
    FROM LIKES
    GROUP BY id_new
) t2
    ON t1.id_new = t2.id_new
```

Note that here a story having no likes would not appear at all in the `LIKES` table and would receive a count of zero.  Also note that I assume that every record in the `LIKES` table corresponds to a logical like.  If not, then the query could be modified to count something else.

Comment: Amazing!, it worked like a charm, it returns everything I needed, I'm liking so much this community already, I don't understand so much about the query, but it is interesting the way it works, I want to know more about this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
SELECT table1.*, table2.*, count(table2.id_like) as like FROM news AS table1 
INNER JOIN likes AS table 2 ON table1.id_new = table2.id_new;
```

OR

```
SELECT table1.*, table2.*, count(table2.id_like) as like FROM news AS table1 
LEFT JOIN likes AS table 2 ON table1.id_new = table2.id_new;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use prepared statement

for example

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM `TABLE_1`);

$stmt2 = $pdo->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM `TABLE_2`);

//then execute

just read more on prepared statement

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT n, (SELECT count(*) FROM like l WHERE l.id_new = n.id_new) FROM news n
```

Answer (score 0):

Use something like :

```
SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM LIKES WHERE LIKES.id_new =id_new) AS newsLikesCount FROM NEWS ORDER BY date;
```

Answer (score 0):

This query would return all news and their number of likes

```
select n1.* , numberOfLikes.number_of_likes
from news n1 
left join 
(select n.id_news, count(l.id_like) as number_of_likes
from news n 
left join likes l on n.id_news = l.id_new
group by n.id_news) numberOfLikes on n1.id_news = numberOfLikes.id_news
```

*The important concepts* here is understanding how two tables are joined together (1), how `group by` works(2), and how to aggregate `l.id_likes` using `count`(3).

(1). Left join preserves everything in the NEWS table and join them
    with news link to the news.

(2). Then we group the rows base on id_news from the news. However,
    mysql gets confused because it doesn't know what to do with id_like
    from the likes table that we included in our select clause. Don't
    worry my friend, This is where count comes in.

(3). We count the number of id_likes base for each id_news since we
    are grouping the rows base on id_news.

I hope this helps. and welcome to StackOverfow. If you find this answer of any other answer helpful please mark it as the solution. That way it will help the community and fellow programmers in the future if they run into the same problem as you. Cheers.

Edit: to include all columns from news table we simply join the result from above back to the news table itself. and we select everything from the news table n1 and only number_of_likes from the result we created above.

Comment: Thanks you so much for your help!, it does work, but it returns only the row count, the total likes, and the rest of information as "new_title, body, date", etc doesn't show up in the array, But it's so interesting the way that query works.

Comment: ah my apology I forgot you want all the columns from news. I edit the query and added the explanation. it should work now. cheers.